# No Update for Location Listener from Vehicle API

Tags: android, fleetboard

I've added the external location listener to my app as suggested. On my test device I do not get any location update. What can I do to receive location updates?

Answer (score 2):

The external location provider does only work in 'real' vehicles where the dispo pilot is connected to the vehicle. The 'external' provider gets location updates from the external antenna which 'should' deliver more accurate results as the internal 'gps' location provider.

To make your app more fault tolerant you can register to both the gps and the external location provider and let the app decide (based on the location accuracy) which location update to use.

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you, but you appear to know something about this topic. These questions have resulted in some amount of confusion, since there's very little information in them about the APIs they're working with (and for that matter, zero information about those APIs on the public web). I've added a tag, if you wouldn't mind [suggesting informative improvements to the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/fleetboard) it would probably save folks a lot of headaches.

Comment: Hi, I think Tobias already added some information on the tag wiki. If you are missing somethink I can take a look to add more information.